# CastError: Cast to string failed for value "{ 'messages._id': '5fac664fc9d37e371d6d64f4' }" at path "_id" for model "Group"

Tags: nodejs, api, mongodb

Necesito  de su ayuda, he estado googleando sobre este error que se me estar presentando en el codigo, y ya tengo la forma de realizarlo, pero no encontro como dar con la solucion...

Les explicos todos los ejemplos que he visto me piden que cree un nuevo objeto, pero al momento de realizarlo no se por donde empezar,

.

este es mi modelo

```
'use strict'

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mongoosePaginate = require('mongoose-paginate-v2');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;


var MessageSchema =  new Schema({

    messageContent:{ type:String },
    idStatusMessage:{ type:Boolean },
    usuario :{ type:Schema.ObjectId, ref:'Usuario'},
    contactos :[{type:Schema.ObjectId, ref:'Contacto'}],
    photoProfile:{ type:String, default:'Image.png'},
},{     versionKey:false,
        timestamps:true, 

});

var Message = mongoose.model('Message' ,MessageSchema);


var GroupsSchema =  new Schema({
   _id: String,
    nameChat:{ type:String },
    usuario :{ type:Schema.ObjectId, ref:'Usuario'},
    contactos :[{type:Schema.ObjectId, ref:'Contacto'}], 
    messageContent:{ type:String },
    messages:[MessageSchema] 
},{     versionKey:false,
        timestamps:true,      
});



//cargar grupos
GroupsSchema.plugin(mongoosePaginate);

module.exports  = mongoose.model('Group',  GroupsSchema);
```

Como pueden observar este modelo tiene un array embebido, que es mensajes, por grupo se tienen varios mensajes y necesito poder encontrar la forma de actualizar el campo mensaje contenido.

controlador

```
updateMssg :function (req, res) {

    //Conseguir ID de comentario por url
    var messagesId = req.params.messagesId;
    console.log(messagesId);
    //recoger datos y validar
    var params = req.body;
    console.log(params);
    
        //validar datos  
        try{
            var validate_messageContent = !validator.isEmpty(params.messageContent);  
        }catch(err){ 
                return  res.status(200).send({
                    message:'no has comentado nada', 
            });
        }
        if(validate_messageContent) {
            // find and update del subdocumento del comentario 
            Group.findByIdAndUpdate(
                { "messages._id": messagesId },
                {
                    "$set": {
                        "messages.$.messageContent":params.messageContent
                    }
                }, 
                {new:true}, 
                (err,groupUpdated)=>{
                   console.log(err,groupUpdated);
                    if(err){
                        return   res.status(500).send({
                            status: 'error',
                            message:'Error en la Peticion'
                        });
                    }
                    
                    if(!groupUpdated){    
                        return   res.status(404).send({
                            status:'error', 
                            message:'no existe el grupo'
                        });
                    }   
                   //devolver los datos
                   return  res.status(200).send({
                        status:"success",
                        group:groupUpdated
                        });   
                   });
           
         }
    
},
```

aqui se encuentra parte de la ruta del controlador.

```
var router = express.Router();
var md_auth=require('../middleware/authenticated');


var multipart = require('connect-multiparty');
var md_upload = multipart({ uploadDir: './uploads/file'});


router.post('/POST_MESSAGE/:groupId', md_auth.authenticated,MensajeController.addMssg);
router.put('/ACTUALIZAR_MENSAJES/:messagesId',md_auth.authenticated, MensajeController.updateMssg);
router.delete('/DELETE_MESSAGE/:groupId/:messageId',md_auth.authenticated,MensajeController.deleteMssg);
```

Error

```
estas pasando por el middleware
5fac664fc9d37e371d6d64f4
[Object: null prototype] { messageContent: 'ey broth' }
CastError: Cast to string failed for value "{ 'messages._id': '5fac664fc9d37e371d6d64f4' }" at path "_id" for model "Group"
    at model.Query.exec 

(C:\Users\Arodr\OneDrive\Escritorio\linkedin\B2B\backendb2b\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4371:21)
  messageFormat: undefined,
  stringValue: `"{ 'messages._id': '5fac664fc9d37e371d6d64f4' }"`,
  kind: 'string',
  value: { 'messages._id': '5fac664fc9d37e371d6d64f4' },
  path: '_id',
  reason: null
} undefined
PUT /api/ACTUALIZAR_MENSAJES/5fac664fc9d37e371d6d64f4 500 83.579 ms - 51
```

He le ido e indican que cambiando las rutas, de lugar, ya lo intente y no funciono, tambien encontre la forma con el metodo objectId de mongoose, pero no encuentro como realizarlo por la misma manera de que creo el nuevo objeto sentenciando el true.

Alguno sabe como puedo aplicar esta forma que pienso que es la mas ideal en mi controlador?

muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La función que estaba efectuando estaba errada, era  findOneAndUpdate.